# How to pass a variable number of parameters to a function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have this multidimensional array (called $values):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 2
        )
)
```

I want to calculate the `diff` between every element (array) of this multidimensional array using `array_diff` PHP function. The first thing I've thought is to split the multidimensional array into single arrays with this:

```
for($cnt = 0; $cnt < count($values); $cnt++){
        for($cntB = 0; $cntB < 4; $cntB++){
            ${'arr'.$cnt}[] = $values[$cnt][$cntB];
        }
    }
```

After this I have several arrays called `$arr1`, `$arr2`, and so on. Since the dimension of the array `$values` may vary (and it will) I can't find a way to pass all the generated single arrays to the function `array_diff`,

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reference: [`func_num_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) and [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Comment: Variable variables (`${'arr'.$cnt}`) is a bad idea in this case.

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but I don't understand what you expect the output to be, could you elaborate? If you just want the list of items in `$array[0]` that aren't in any of the other ones (i.e., array_diff), then see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, as I didn't read all of that, but check out:

```
call_user_func_array('array_diff', $values)
```

Maybe that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function diff() {
    $args = func_get_args();

    // $args how has all the arrays you passed in.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
${'arr'.$cnt}[] = ...
```

use

```
$arr[$cnt][] = ...
```

Problem solved. :)

There's no need for variable variables when what you're really looking for is an array.

Comment: I agree, but then isn't that entire loop just longhand for `$arr = $values`?

Comment: @konf Now that you mention it, it is. :)