# PHP splitting an array to pass as parameters

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass a variable number of parameters to a function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402333/how-to-pass-a-variable-number-of-parameters-to-a-function-in-php)

I'm trying to dynamically populate parameters when calling a method based on get requests.

For example:

Let's say I have an array with four values:

`array(1, 2, 3, 4);`

Now I want to pass this to a method that accepts these four parameters.  However, this needs to be dynamic, so I can't just do for example `method($array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3])`.

My question is, how can I take an array with variable lengths and pass it to methods that may also accept varying parameters?

Thank you!

Comment: Would you like Keyword Argument ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
function method($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4){
    echo "$arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4";
}
call_user_func_array(method, array(1, 2, 3, 4));//prints 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect.  I ended up doing it like this as I'm calling a method within a class `call_user_function_array(array($class_object, 'method'), array(1, 2, 3, 4));`  Thanks so much!